# XSLT - Concatenate Child Values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, parent-child, xslt-1.0

I have a sample XML like this:

```
<Record id="1">
 <Field id="1" name="Field1">
  <ListValues>
   <ListValue id="1" displayName="Bank">Bank</ListValue>
   <ListValue id="2" displayName="Personal">Personal</ListValue>
  </ListValues>
 </Field>
 <Field id="2" name="Field2"/>
</Record>
```

I need to combine all the IDs to create a Key Field in my output XML, something like this:

```
<Record>
 <KeyField>1-1-12</KeyField>
</Record>
```

This key field is the concat of Record Id, Field Id (of Field1 - always) and the children of Field1. These children (ListValue) can have more than 100-150 values, and I need to combine them to form my key field (it's optional to use delimiters).

Currently, I am performing the same in this manner:

```
<KeyField>
 <xsl:value-of select="concat(../Record/@id,'-',Field[@name='Field1']/@id,'-', concat(Field[@name='Field1']/ListValues/ListValue/@id,Field[@name='Field1']/ListValues/ListValue[2]/@id, and so on..))"/>
</KeyField>
```

The problem is if I have 100-150 such values, I can't go on adding those many in the KeyField element. Is there a way I can precalculate this and just use it in my key field element, also, how do I loop through all such values?

I am using XSL 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have found a solution to this in XSLT 2.0:

I created a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="Key_NewField">
 <xsl:value-of select="Field[@name='Field1']/ListValues/ListValue[position() &lt;= 150]/@id" />
</xsl:variable>
```

and then used this variable ($Key_NewField) in the `<KeyField>` element as part of the last concatenation.

This give me the output (which is desired):

```
<Record>
 <KeyField>1-1-1 2</KeyField>
</Record>
```

For XSLT (1.0):

```
<xsl:variable name="Key_NewField">
 <xsl:for-each select="Field[@name = 'Field1']/ListValues/ListValue">
  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

which gives me the following output:

```
<Record>
 <KeyField>1-1-12</KeyField>
</Record>
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is an XSL 1.0 solution with a named template that can be called for retrieving the keyfield per record.

XML used:

```
<Record id="1">
 <Field id="1" name="Field1">
  <ListValues>
   <ListValue id="1" displayName="Bank">Bank</ListValue>
   <ListValue id="2" displayName="Personal">Personal</ListValue>
   <ListValue id="3" displayName="Personal">Personal</ListValue>
   <ListValue id="4" displayName="Personal">Personal</ListValue>
   <ListValue id="5" displayName="Personal">Personal</ListValue>
   <ListValue id="6" displayName="Personal">Personal</ListValue>
   <ListValue id="7" displayName="Personal">Personal</ListValue>
   <ListValue id="8" displayName="Personal">Personal</ListValue>
  </ListValues>
 </Field>
 <Field id="2" name="Field2"/>
</Record>
```

XSLT used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

  <xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:for-each select="/Record">

          <xsl:element name="Record">
              <xsl:call-template name="GetKeyField">
                  <xsl:with-param name="record" select="current()" />
              </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:element>

      </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="GetKeyField">
      <xsl:param name="record" />
      <xsl:variable name="recordId" select="$record/@id" />
      <xsl:variable name="fieldId" select="$record/Field[@name='Field1']/@id" />
      <xsl:variable name="listValueIds">
          <xsl:for-each select="$record/Field[@name='Field1']//ListValue">
              <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:element name="KeyField">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat($recordId, '-', $fieldId, '-', $listValueIds))" />
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

RESULT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record><KeyField>1-1-12345678</KeyField></Record>
```

Comment: Thanks Jasper, the above solution is somewhat similar to the one I have posted as well. Thank you very much. It gives me an option to create a named template like you did.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
<xsl:template match="Record">
   <xsl:element name="Keyfield">
      <xsl:value-of select="@id" />-<xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field">
   <xsl:value-of select="@id" />-
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ListValues><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ListValue><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></xsl:template>
```

Just typed in! so excuse typos!

Comment: This solution doesn't give me the expected output, instead it gives dashes and spaces.